# Creating a subscription through Stripe-payments

Tags: python, stripe-payments, subscription

I threw this together earlier today:

```
import stripe 

stripe.api_key = "sk_test_key"

stripe.Token.create(
  card={
    "number": '4242424242424242',
    "exp_month": 12,
    "exp_year": 2018,
    "cvc": '123'
  },
)

stripe.Customer.create(
  description="test test test",
  source="tok_visa"
)

stripe.Customer.list(limit=1)

stripe.Subscription.create(
  customer="id",
  items=[
    {
      "plan": "1",
    },
  ],
)
```

Running this returns with this

```
read-only@bash: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 28, in <module> "plan": "1",
  File "/tmp/stripe/api_resources/subscription.py", line 33, in create return super(Subscription, cls).create(**params)
  File "/tmp/stripe/api_resources/abstract/createable_api_resource.py", line 17, in create response, api_key = requestor.request('post', url, params, headers)
  File "/tmp/stripe/api_requestor.py", line 152, in request resp = self.interpret_response(rbody, rcode, rheaders)
  File "/tmp/stripe/api_requestor.py", line 359, in interpret_response self.handle_error_response(rbody, rcode, resp, rheaders)
  File "/tmp/stripe/api_requestor.py", line 177, in handle_error_response raise err
stripe.error.InvalidRequestError: Request req_ZmLk0oWGjmrkut: No such customer: id
```

This seems to be an error or I'm just putting the wrong value in "customer"

Any ideas on on what to do?

Comment: Should the value for `customer` in the `stripe.Subscription.create` call actually be a unique id based on the customer you get from `stripe.Customer.list` rather than the string `"id"`?

Comment: Thats what I'm trying to get at. It works with `Customer.create`, taking `tok_visa` and using it as a stand in for `tok_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`, appending the info automatically. but for the customer, I'm unsure what the stand in here would be.

Comment: `stripe.Customer.create(..)` returns the Customer object. Take that and pass its id into `stripe.Subscription.create(..)`. I.e. `customer = stripe.Customer.create(...); stripe.Subscription.create(
  customer=customer.id, ...`